# Diagram in Tikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm looking to create something like this in Tikz environment. Any tips? help?

[image]

Comment: Hi. What have you tried?

Comment: There is the forest package, which is based on tikz. And tikz has a trees library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `forest` package allows you to recreate these figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={rounded corners,text=white,font=\sffamily,align=center,
grow'=east,forked edges,edge = {semithick, -stealth}, % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333597/121799
anchor=west,l sep=2.5em,
if level=0{fill=green!60!black}{},
if level=1{fill=blue!70,minimum width={1.1*width("Merkmal beliebig")}}{},
if level=2{fill=blue,minimum width={1.1*width("Varianz unbekannt")}}{},
}
[Erwartungswert $\mu$
 [Merkmal\\ normalverteilt
  [Varianz bekannt]
  [Varianz unbekannt]
 ]
 [Merkmal beliebig\\ verteilt]
]
\end{forest}
\bigskip

\begin{forest}
for tree={rounded corners,text=white,font=\sffamily,align=center,
grow'=east,forked edges,edge = {semithick, -stealth}, % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333597/121799
anchor=west,l sep=3.5em,
if level=0{fill=green!60!black}{},
if level=1{fill=blue!70,minimum width={1.1*width("Merkmal beliebig")}}{},
}
[Varianz $\sigma^2$
 [Merkmal\\ normalverteilt
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: after `l sep = 2.5em,`  i would add  `fork sep = 1.2em,` :-). nice answer!

Comment: @Zarko Thanks! I agree! (The OP now knows what to do. ;-)

Comment: @marmot, i wonder why is needed to multiply `width("...")` with `1.1` that both nodes in level have equal width (or write for example as `minimum width={width(" Merkmal beliebig ")}`?

Comment: @Zarko This is not necessary, I only used one possible way of making the nodes equally wide at each level and having some grace distance on both sides. There are more sophisticated methods which I was too lazy too look up. I believe when getting exposed to forest for the first time one should not get overwhelmed with something like `max(width(content))` (I just made this up but there are such options).

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to @marmot's nice answer:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    filv/.style={
        fill=green!50!black,
        font=\color{white},
        rectangle,
        rounded corners=3pt,
        minimum width=3.5cm
    },
    selv/.style={
        fill=cyan!50!black,
        font=\color{white},
        rectangle,
        rounded corners=3pt,
        minimum width=3.5cm,
        align=center
    },
    thlv/.style={
        fill=blue!30!black,
        font=\color{white},
        rectangle,
        rounded corners=3pt,
        minimum width=3.5cm
    }
]
\node[filv] (lv1-1) {Erwartungswert $\mu$};
\node[filv,below=2cm of lv1-1.south] (lv1-2) {Varianz $\sigma^2$};
\node[selv,above right=0.25cm and 1.5cm of lv1-1.east] (lv2-1) {Merkmal\\ normalverteilt};
\node[selv,below right=0.25cm and 1.5cm of lv1-1.east] (lv2-2) {Merkmal beliebig\\ verteilt};
\node[selv,right=1.5cm of lv1-2.east] (lv2-3) {Merkmal\\ normalverteilt};
\node[thlv,right=1.5cm of lv2-1.north east] (lv3-1) {Varianz bekannt};
\node[thlv,right=1.5cm of lv2-1.south east] (lv3-2) {Varianz unbekannt};
\draw[-latex] (lv1-2)--(lv2-3);
\coordinate[right=0.75cm of lv1-1.east] (mid1);
\coordinate[left=0.75cm of lv2-1.west] (mid1-a);
\coordinate[left=0.75cm of lv2-2.west] (mid1-b);
\draw (lv1-1)--(mid1);
\draw[latex-latex] (lv2-2)--(mid1-b)--(mid1-a)--(lv2-1);
\coordinate[right=0.75cm of lv2-1.east] (mid2);
\coordinate[left=0.75cm of lv3-1.west] (mid2-a);
\coordinate[left=0.75cm of lv3-2.west] (mid2-b);
\draw (lv2-1)--(mid2);
\draw[latex-latex] (lv3-2)--(mid2-b)--(mid2-a)--(lv3-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

for completness ... pure `tikz` version with using `trees` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \tikzset{
  base/.style = {rounded corners,
                 text=white, font=\sffamily,
                 minimum width=20ex,
                 align=center},
    L1/.style = {base, fill=teal},
    L2/.style = {base, fill=cyan!80!black},
    L3/.style = {base, fill=cyan!60!black},
   grow=east,
   edge from parent fork right,
   level distance = 37mm,
   level 1/.style = {sibling distance=16mm},
   level 2/.style = {sibling distance = 8mm},
    edge from parent/.style = {draw, semithick, -latex}
            }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[L1] {Erwartungswert $\mu$}
    child {node[L2] {Merkmal\\ normalverteilt}
        child {node[L3] {Varianz bekannt}}
        child {node[L3] {Varianz unbekannt}}
          }
    child {node[L2] {Merkmal beliebig\\ verteilt}}
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[L1] {Varianz $\sigma^2$}
    child {node[L2] {Merkmal\\ normalverteilt}}
   ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

of course, with `forest` is more simply and elegant solution

Comment: How did you get that nice green border around the image?

Comment: @JohnD, for showing image in answer I use Snipping Tool by which I can cut part of image showed on screen and store it in my answer.  It has option to draw line around selected image in selected color. It is not part of code in answer.