# Forest package: problems with height

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I am having trouble with the height of the arrows, how can I fix it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur,shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{grimsel/.style={rectangle split,rectangle split parts=1,draw,
    fill=white,blur shadow,rounded corners,align=center}}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\NodeTitle}[2][]{#2\nodepart[align=left,text width={width("#2")}]{two}}
\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={grimsel,edge={-latex}}
[Recommender Systems,l=17mm,
 [ Approach \\ Content Based,l=17mm]
 [Approach \\ Filtrado Colaborativo,l=17mm,
  [{Memory \\Based }
   [{User  \\ Based}]
   [{Item  \\ Based}]   
]
  [{Model\\ Based}
   [{Clustering \\methos}]
   [{Matrix factorization \\ Method}]
   [{Neural \\ Networks}]
  ]
 ]
 [{Hybrid\\approach  \nodepart[align=left]{two} },l=17mm]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What precisely do you mean by the height of the arrows?

Comment: Like the lenght of the arrows, the separation between rectangles.. As an example, below Recommendation Systems, the arrow's length is not large enough. A good length is like for the arrows that are pointing towards the three rectangles corresponding to the second line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some help from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333597/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur,shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{grimsel/.style={rectangle split,rectangle split parts=1,draw,
    fill=white,blur shadow,rounded corners,align=center}}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\NodeTitle}[2][]{#2\nodepart[align=left,text width={width("#2")}]{two}}
\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={grimsel,thick,edge={-latex,very thick},l sep = 12mm,fork sep=6mm}
[Recommender Systems,
 [ Approach \\ Content Based]
 [Approach \\ Filtrado Colaborativo,calign with current 
  [{Memory \\Based }
   [{User  \\ Based}]
   [{Item  \\ Based}]   
]
  [{Model\\ Based}
   [{Clustering \\methos}]
   [{Matrix factorization \\ Method},calign with current]
   [{Neural \\ Networks}]
  ]
 ]
 [{Hybrid\\approach  \nodepart[align=left]{two} }]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes!!! That's exactly what I was looking for!!! Thank you Marmot