# organisation chart drawn with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

though i have drawn flowchart with tikz but i need to now graduate to a landscape organisation chart--normal charts use rectangles placed one under the other--is there a way to first make the vertical charts separately and them in the end of the  code simply give them a horizontal joins where required

a normal vertical chart shown below

[image]

but i need to graduate to this as below

[image]

thinkin that first draw the verticval boxes then in the end a horizontal join

any thoughts? are welcome
could it visually better in any other mmethod for example in the windows explorer style for folders and subfolders

is smart draw better for this type of drawing or tikz or asymptote

Comment: The perhaps most convenient way to draw this *tree* might be `forest`. But even there it is some effort, and you may not find anyone who is willing to punch in the texts from a screen shot for you.

Comment: as I see forest gives slanted joins--is it possible to get vertical /forizontal joins as above--no need for anyone else to do it will do it myself--its my work--just required a start

Comment: Sure, you only need `forked edges`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495968.

Comment: roger --out--will follow up

Comment: With `forest`, you will need to either annotate with `tikz+` or regular Ti*k*Z commands for some of the arrows or, alternatively, abuse `edge path'`. Not difficult, but a bit fiddly. If you get stuck, post your code so people have something to work with.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333597/ may also be helpful. [Disclaimer: my answer.]