# Positioning of nodes in Forest

Tags: forest

I am trying to make a decision tree for cancer treatment options. Here is what I have so far:
[image]

I would like the NED node to be changed in the following ways:

1. I would like it to be positioned higher up on the page (or, equivalently, to have the Recurrence node positioned lower down on the page)
2. I would like the the left edge of the NED node to be aligned with the left edge of the Recurrence node.

Here is a hand drawing of what I would like the start of the tree to look like:
[image]

Note: I have based my code from this post: [Package forest: use of forked edge and forked edges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333595/package-forest-use-of-forked-edge-and-forked-edges)

Here is my code so far:

```
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}


%adapted from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333595/package-forest-use-of-forked-edge-and-forked-edges
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    font=\small,
    draw,
    semithick,
    rounded corners,
    align = center,
    inner sep = 2mm,
    edge = {semithick, -stealth},
    grow = east,
    l sep = 19mm,
    fork sep=3mm,
  }
  [Active \\ Surveillance, fit = band
    [Recurrence
    [Other sites
        [Chemotherapy
            [PC-RPLND]
            [NED]
        ]
    ]
    [TM elevated
        [Chemotherapy
            [PC-RPLND]
            [NED]
        ]
        [RPLND
            [Chemotherapy]
            [NED]
        ]
    ]
    [Retroperitoneal recurrence \\ TM elevated,
        [RPLND
            [Chemotherapy]
            [NED]
            ]
        [Chemotherapy
            [PC-RPLND]
            [NED]
        ]
    ]
    [Retroperitoneal recurrence \\ TM normal
        [RPLND
            [Chemotherapy]
            [NED]
        ]
    ]   
     ]
    [NED, l =40mm]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: left aligning third and fourth generation children]

This is a very simple modification of [Sašo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700185/), Since `anchor` is already `west`, it is sufficient to set `tier/.option=level` to ensure all nodes in a given generation are aligned by their left edges.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700208/
% addaswyd o ateb Sašo: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700185/
%adapted from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333595/package-forest-use-of-forked-edge-and-forked-edges
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    font=\small,
    draw,
    semithick,
    rounded corners,
    align = center,
    inner sep = 2mm,
    edge = {semithick, -stealth},
    grow = east,
    l sep = 19mm,
    fork sep=3mm,
    fit=band,
    anchor=west,
    tier/.option=level
  }
  [Active \\ Surveillance
    [Recurrence
    [Other sites
        [Chemotherapy
            [PC-RPLND]
            [NED]
        ]
    ]
    [TM elevated
        [Chemotherapy
            [PC-RPLND]
            [NED]
        ]
        [RPLND
            [Chemotherapy]
            [NED]
        ]
    ]
    [Retroperitoneal recurrence \\ TM elevated,
        [RPLND
            [Chemotherapy]
            [NED]
            ]
        [Chemotherapy
            [PC-RPLND]
            [NED]
        ]
    ]
    [Retroperitoneal recurrence \\ TM normal
        [RPLND
            [Chemotherapy]
            [NED]
        ]
    ]   
     ]
    [NED]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

## Edit

[In response to comment asking how to integrate a style like that shown for the decision tree on pages 83-84 of `forest`'s manual.]

The case here is a little more complicated because, unlike the example decision tree, we sometimes have cases of 0, 1, 2 and 4 children. I've therefore calculated half the number of children plus one and set the labels above or below the `edge`s according to whether the child's `n` is less than the result (for `below`) or not (for `above`). Since these are probabilities, I assume the case where there is only a single child can be ignored. (The code works in that case, but the label isn't always where I might prefer to put it.) In other trees, it might make sense to accommodate this case specifically or to use a different rule for placement altogether.

The node's content and its label's content should be separated by a colon. I've used single letters as placeholders for probabilities. For example, `aardvark:animal` would produce a node containing 'aardvark' and an `edge label` containing 'animal'.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700208/
% addaswyd o ateb Sašo: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700185/
%adapted from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333595/package-forest-use-of-forked-edge-and-forked-edges
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    font=\small,
    draw,
    semithick,
    rounded corners,
    align = center,
    inner sep = 2mm,
    edge = {semithick, -stealth},
    grow = east,
    l sep = 19mm,
    fork sep=3mm,
    fit=band,
    anchor=west,
    tier/.option=level
  },
  before typesetting nodes={%
    where n children=0{}{%
      tempcounta/.option=n children,
      tempcounta'+=1,
      for children={%
        split option={content}{:}{content,split edge label}, 
      },
    },
  },
  split edge label/.style={%
    if={>ORw+n<{n}{tempcounta}{##1/2}}{%
      edge label+={node [pos=0.75,below] {#1}}
    }{%
      edge label+={node [pos=0.75,above] {#1}}
    },
  }
  [Active \\ Surveillance
    [Recurrence:A
      [Other sites:a
          [Chemotherapy
              [PC-RPLND:c]
              [NED:d]
          ]
      ]
      [TM elevated:e
          [Chemotherapy:f
              [PC-RPLND:g]
              [NED:h]
          ]
          [RPLND:i
              [Chemotherapy:j]
              [NED:b]
          ]
      ]
      [Retroperitoneal recurrence \\ TM elevated:k,
          [RPLND:t
              [Chemotherapy:l]
              [NED:m]
              ]
          [Chemotherapy:s
              [PC-RPLND:n]
              [NED:o]
          ]
      ]
      [Retroperitoneal recurrence \\ TM normal:p
          [RPLND:q
              [Chemotherapy:v]
              [NED:r]
          ]
      ]   
    ]
    [NED:B]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: tree with added edge labels]

Comment: Yes, this is perfect! Thank you. One other question: How would I place a small piece of text to indicate the probabilities? I tried reading the forest manual, and found something that looked like what I want on page 83 (https://mirror.mwt.me/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf). However, I was not able to duplicate that code in my example.

Comment: @Sam Do you mean the decision tree which splits the content of the nodes to create labels midway along the edges? (The picture at the bottom of 83 with `N` as the root node?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am referring to!

Comment: @Sam See edit above.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! I want to try and study your code and see if I can understand it, so that I can make any modifications on my own without bothering you :) If I have more questions after reading your code, I will leave a comment.

Comment: @Sam Sounds good, though whether I'll be able to answer them is another matter ;). The automated positioning of `edge label` is pretty common - at least, it's a feature of a fair number of my `forest` answers on this site. Dealing with 4 children is less usual. I've mostly used this kind of style in things like decision trees where every choice point is binary.

Answer (score 4):

`fit=band` is the right idea, but it should appear on the `NED` node (where `l=40mm` should be removed).

Alternatively (and as shown below), `fit=band` can be applied to the entire tree, by including it among keys in `for tree`.

For the desired alignment, include `anchor=west`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}


%adapted from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333595/package-forest-use-of-forked-edge-and-forked-edges
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    font=\small,
    draw,
    semithick,
    rounded corners,
    align = center,
    inner sep = 2mm,
    edge = {semithick, -stealth},
    grow = east,
    l sep = 19mm,
    fork sep=3mm,
    fit=band,
    anchor=west,
  }
  [Active \\ Surveillance
    [Recurrence
    [Other sites
        [Chemotherapy
            [PC-RPLND]
            [NED]
        ]
    ]
    [TM elevated
        [Chemotherapy
            [PC-RPLND]
            [NED]
        ]
        [RPLND
            [Chemotherapy]
            [NED]
        ]
    ]
    [Retroperitoneal recurrence \\ TM elevated,
        [RPLND
            [Chemotherapy]
            [NED]
            ]
        [Chemotherapy
            [PC-RPLND]
            [NED]
        ]
    ]
    [Retroperitoneal recurrence \\ TM normal
        [RPLND
            [Chemotherapy]
            [NED]
        ]
    ]   
     ]
    [NED]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: resulting tree]

Comment: This is helpful, but the 3rd generation children and the 4th generation children are not left aligned. Do you know how to fix this? (I can include a picture in my original question if this would be useful.)

Comment: @Sam See below. Is that what you mean by 'left aligned'?